# How Do I update the Dom (Re-render element) when value changes?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

So I have a variable startWeek, that is being displayed and when I click a button, a Have a method that will add 7 days to the date. I want the page to show the new date but not sure how to go about doing this?

I want to get the dates to transition in and out everytime the date range is updated, but Im not sure how to do it. I have thought about using two v-if statements and transitioning back and fourth between them but im sure there is a better way. I have looked into watchers and computed properties but im not quite sure if they are the answer or how to implement them in this given situation.

Example:

```
<template>
<b-button @click="subtractWeek(7)></b-button>
<span id="thingIwantToUpdateInDOM">{{ startWeek + " - " + endWeek}}</span>
<b-button @click="addWeek(7)></b-button>
</template>


export default {
   data(){
    return{
           startWeek: null,
           endWeek: null,
          }
         },
methods: { 
   addWeek(days){
      this.startWeek.setDate(this.startWeek.getDate() + days)
      this.endWeek.setDate(this.endWeek.getDate() + days)
    },
substractWeek(7){
      this.startWeek.setDate(this.startWeek.getDate() - days)
      this.endWeek.setDate(this.endWeek.getDate() - days)
    },
getInitialDate(){
     this.startWeek = new Date();
     var tempEndWeek = new Date();
     this.endWeek = tempEndWeek;
  },
created() {
this.getInitialDate();
}
 }
}
```

My ultimate goal is to have the date range to swipe our transition out similar to a carousel effect on every button click or value change. Any bit of advise is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your end goal is lots of optimizations away, but the snippet below should get you started. Your date operations are fine, so a few notes about the implementation:

- I don't exactly know the internals of how Vue does state change tracking in the `data` objects, but I'm fairly sure it involves [getter and setter property accessors](https://javascript.info/property-accessors). When you do `this.x = new Date(); this.x.setDate(this.x.getDate() + 7);`, `this.x` tracks the date object and not its value, so the change will not be seen by Vue. You need to clone the date first, set a new date, and then **reassign** it to `this.x` (see the navigateWeeks method below).
- **watch** is useful when you want to **react to a single, specific property change**, in your case, the dynamic `startWeek` is a perfect candidate. If the fact that something changed is more important than *what* exactly, use the `updated` hook (typical use-case: destroying & re-initializing 3rd party library widgets with new parameters).
- **computed** is useful for **keeping a property derived from another property in sync at all times**, in your example the endDate is always 7 days after the startDate, so it is a perfect candidate for this. In the snippet I also used a computed value for the ISO date format that HTML date inputs expect.

  - Finally, you can do quite advanced stuff with `setTimeout`, some CSS keyframes, and toggling a `.transitioning` class

```js
Vue.component('fading-date', {
  template: `
    <span><input :class="className" type="date" :value="htmlValue"></span>
  `,
  props: {
    value: { type: Date },
    fadeDuration: { type: Number, default: 1 }
  },
  data() { 
    return { transitioning: false, timer: null };
  },
  computed: {
    htmlValue() {
      return this.value.toISOString().split('T')[0];
    },
    className() {
      return this.transitioning ? 'transitioning' : '';
    }
  },
  watch: {
    value() {
      clearTimeout(this.timer);
      this.transitioning = true;
      this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
        this.transitioning = false;
      }, 1000 * this.fadeDuration);
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedWeek: new Date()
  },
  computed: {
    weekAfterSelected() {
      const date = this.selectedWeek;
      const endDate = new Date(date);
      endDate.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
      return endDate;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    navigateWeeks(numWeeks = 1) {
      const newDate = new Date(this.selectedWeek);
      newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + (7 * numWeeks));
      this.selectedWeek = newDate;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
input[type="date"] {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}

@keyframes fade{
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}


.transitioning {
  animation: fade ease-out 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <fading-date :value="selectedWeek" :fade-duration="1"></fading-date>
  <fading-date :value="weekAfterSelected" :fade-duration="1"></fading-date>
  <br>
  <button type="button" @click="navigateWeeks(-1)">A week sooner</button>
  <button type="button" @click="navigateWeeks(1)">A week later</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Beutiful, Thanks so much for the explanation especially the explanation on what vue can, and cant see. Thanks so much!